# Is there a 'revert' function for FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have a calendar events that have custom properties one being isPublished which can be changed on the fly so I can't set the editable value to false.  I am wondering how to cause an event to revert to its previous location on the calendar if it is marked isPublished.

```
eventDrop: function (event, jsEvent, ui, view){
            //event.start = dateAdd(d,dayDelta,event.start);
            if (event.isPublished == 0){
                addEditEvent(event);
            } else {
                revert: true;
                console.log('revert');
            }

        },
```

I see in the doc that there is a dragRevertDuration but I can't find the revert itself, is there one?

Comment: Although I didn't figure this out I changed it so that the event was marked editable:false at the same time that isPublished is changed to 0.  Still would have preferred to revert the event but not editable works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes it does, pretty simple

```
eventDrop: function (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc) {
    if (event.isPublished == 0){
        addEditEvent(event);
    } else {
        revertFunc();
        console.log('revert');
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent!  I knew it had to be something easy I was missing. thank Kim!